# Including a function of the lagged dependent variable

Tags: panel-data, lags, dynamic-regression

I am trying to establish a relation between a new regulation and the stock market investment behaviour of people. To do so, I have a set of panel data, which has people (i) over multiple years (t).

```
INVESTMENTit= α + β*REGULATIONt + β*TREATEDi + 
              β*REGULATIONt*TREATEDi + ϵ
```

However, the regulation only applies to people who last year had less than 2x annual income in investment. So, the strength of the effect should depend on the distance between 2x income and lagged investments. If my income is 50k and I already have 125k in investments, I should be unaffected. If I have 50k investments, I would be strongly affected, if I have 95k investments, I would be weakly affected. Therefore, I would like to interact with:

```
(INCOMEit*2 - INVESTMENTit-1)
```

new equation:

```
INVESTMENTit= α + β*REGULATIONt + β*TREATEDi + 
     β*REGULATIONt*TREATEDi + β*REGULATIONt*(INCOMEit*2 - 
     INVESTMENTit - 1) + β*TREATEDi*(INCOMEit*2-INVESTMENTit-1) + 
     β*REGULATIONt*TREATEDi*(INCOMEit*2-INVESTMENTit -1) + 
     β*(INCOMEit*2-INVESTMENTit-1)+ϵ
```

However, this is a function of my lagged dependent variable. I know that if I included the lag of investments without taking a function of it I would need an Arellano-Bond estimator to overcome endogeneity concerns.

Are these concerns equally valid for functions of the dependent variable?
Would I need to create a strange modification of Arellano-Bond to overcome it?

Comment: Please use math markup to make your equations easier to read, see https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated?noredirect=1